# Is $s(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{\alpha^i}{(n-i)^\beta}$ decreasing in $n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, upper-lower-bounds

Assume $\alpha \in (0,1), \beta > 0$. Consider this sum

\begin{align}
s(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{\alpha^i}{(n-i)^\beta}
\end{align}

Can we show an upper bound $b(n)$ on $s(n)$ that is decreasing in $n$ for some finite $\beta$ (e.g. $\beta = 2$)? Specifically, I want $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b(n) = 0$.

Attempt: It is easy to see that the above sum is bounded independent of $\alpha$. For example for $\beta = 2$:
$$
s(n) \leq \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{(n-i)^2} \leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2} < 2. 
$$

Intuitively, it seems that $s(n)$ includes the sum of a few $1/n^\beta$ terms and the rest of the terms are small due to exponential decay $\alpha^i$.

Here is the plot for $\beta =1$:

[image]

Comment: Well done for improving your question!

Comment: Why don't just use $\frac{1}{1-\alpha}$, can you be more clear on what you expect? For example,  is the thing you want is the asymptotic order of $s(n)$?

Comment: I'm looking for a bound that is decreasing in $n$ e.g. showing that $s(n) < 1/n$, so $1/(1-\alpha)$ doesn't work. @ParesseuxNguyen

Comment: Well, $\frac{1}{1-\alpha}$ is already decreasing in $n$, if you want it you can modify it to be $ b(n)= \frac{1}{1-\alpha}+\frac{1}{n}$. There are infinite possibilities and the freedom to choose such a bound is too much.

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen Right! I edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyways, here is a simple proof for an upper bound.
Noticing the $(\alpha^i , 0 \le i \le n-1)$ is increasing in $i$ and $( \frac{1}{(n-i)^{\beta}}, 0 \le i \le n-1)$ is decreasing in $i$, by the Chebysev's inequality for monotonic sequences, we imply that:
$$s(n) \le \frac{1}{n}\left( \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \alpha^i \right)\left(  \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{(n-i)^{\beta}}\right)  $$
So
$$\begin{align}
s(n) &\le \frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{1-\alpha}(1-\beta)n^{1-\beta}=\frac{1-\beta}{1-\alpha}n^{-\beta} \quad & \text{ if } \beta < 1
\\
s(n) &\le \frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\ln(n) &\text{ if } \beta = 1
\\
s(n) &\le \frac{1}{n}\frac{\beta}{1-\alpha} & \text{if } \beta >1
\end{align}$$